# How do i add strings to in the middle of the list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list with lots of strings in it

this is part of the list

```
<Setting cmd="SPLIT_SS" cmdindex="1" description="" name="static_session_time_gap" type="double" value="120.0"/>\n', '    <Setting cmd="USE_DOPPLER" cmdindex="0" description="" format="OFF/ON" name="phase_doppler" type="int" value="0"/>\n', '    <Setting cmd="USE_DOPPLER" cmdindex="1" description="" format="OFF/ON" name="code_doppler" type="int" value="0"/>\n', '    <Settings name="UserCmds"/>\n', '  </Settings>\n', '\n', '  <Settings name="INS">\n', '    <Settings name="Biases">\n'
```

I want to add this string:`Setting name="OMITEX" value="PROC ALL PPP_ELEV_MASK ALL"`

to right after: `Settings name="UserCmds"`

Ive tried this:

```
num_lines = 0
for i,Line in enumerate(NewProcProfile):
num_lines += 1
if 'UserCmds' in Line:
    linestart = num_lines + 1
    num_lines = 0 
    for i,Line in enumerate(NewProcProfile):
        num_lines += 1
        if num_lines == linestart:
            comment = '  <Setting name="OMITEX" value="PROC ALL {0} ALL"/>'.format(Parameter)
            NewLine2 = '{0}'.format(comment)
            NewProcProfile.append(NewLine2)
```

But it just appends it to the end of the list.  How can i get it to add it right after the 'UserCmds' string?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want to do, how about using `list.insert()` method?

Here is an example (`l` is the list):

```
item_to_add = 'Setting name="OMITEX" value="PROC ALL PPP_ELEV_MASK ALL"'
for index, line in enumerate(l):
    if "UserCmds" in line:
        l.insert(index + 1, item_to_add)
        break
```